# Detect 3 tap on iPhone device backside

Tags: iphone, ios, accelerometer

I am working on an application where I need to detect 3 tap anywhere on iPhone device. I know we can detect tap on iPhone screen but this time I need to detect everywhere on iPhone device such as iPhone backside.

Comment: None of the currently shipping iPhones (or iPads or iPods) have sensors on the back of the phone. You might want to rethink your idea.

Comment: Yes, I know there is not available sensor for this.But I think It may be possible by the use of Acceelerometer.

Comment: In that case you should reword you question to be more specific and list what accelerometer techniques you've tried.

Comment: This generally just isn't a good idea; many people have cases on their devices which will make it harder to detect taps elsewhere on the device (if it won't already be hard, which it probably is).

Comment: Hello Rahul, I am working on same functionality. Have you achieved it? If yes then can you share your thoughts please how did you do that. I am analyzing the accelerometers values i have on taps when values changes quite often then it should display an Alert. but it can be buggy as if user walking fast or take a jump. in that case alert will occur as well. 

So kindly let me know if you have achieved this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you get 3 Tap at Iphone screen everywhere in your app(not for iphone all app) of UIView you just need to implement code in EachViewController `ViewdidLoad` method like:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 3;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    [tapGesture release];
}

- (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized) {
        // handling code
    }
}
```

**you can do this stuff for only your crated app not for backside(Iphone Device).**

Comment: It works only for UIView (iPhone screen). But I need to know to detect tap anywhere on iPhone device.

Answer (score 1):

For recognizing taps on the back of the phone you could try to evaluate the acceleration sensor's data. But in order to get significant accelerations, the user must tap quite hard.

Comment: You are right, I am using acceleration sensor's data combinations for this, but no success.

Comment: Are the signal peaks to weak? If yes, I'm afraid there's no way of recognizing taps on the phone's back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UITapGestureRecognizer` for detecting tap gesture on iPhone screen.
It has `numberOfTapsRequired` for number of taps count and `numberOfTouchesRequired` for tapping fingers count.

And we couldn't know whether user tap on iPhone backside. :(

Comment: Thanks, I know tap gesture. It works only on iPhone screen but i need detect tap everywhere on iPhone device.